# Yii CActiveForm Validation issue

Tags: php, yii

I having difficulties to understand CActiveForm validation, how does it work?
This my form:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'swim-subscribe-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'action'=>"/mycontroller/myfunction"
        ));

echo $form->labelEx($model, 'companion_tel', array('label' => 'telefon:'));
$this->endWidget();
```

and in the myfunction I have:

```
if (isset($_POST)) 
$model->attributes = $_POST;
   if ($model->save()) {
       $this->redirect('/another_controller');
   }
}
```

and in the model I have:

```
class myModel extends ActiveRecord {
  public $companion_tel;
  public function rules() {
  return array(
            array('companion_tel' , 'required', 'message'=>'Invalid !'),
  );
}
}
```

Actually I want to show the message Invalid after submit. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in simple way

```
 if (isset($_POST['YourForm'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['YourForm'];

            if ($model->validate()) {
                if ($model->save()) {
                    $this->redirect('/another_controller');
                }

        }
 }

$this->render('YourViewName', array('model' => $model));
```

and inside view add the error

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'swim-subscribe-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'action'=>"/mycontroller/myfunction"
        ));
 echo $form->error($model,'companion_tel'); //error
echo $form->labelEx($model, 'companion_tel', array('label' => 'telefon:'));
$this->endWidget();
```

Comment: If I write if ($model->validate()){  .... }else{ echo "failed"}. It displays me always the message failed. It does not render the view.

Comment: add $this->render('viewName', array('model' => $model));, I edit may answer check it

Comment: yeah it works. but I got another problem: Before I go to my form there were executed several ajax events. It loads my view I got the validation message, but I lost css, menu, and other things. any idea what should I do ?

Comment: any idea to my previous question ?

Comment: where are the css, menu in your page ? is it in the same form view? are you call the form using ajax; you can post your code in another question

Comment: Is this possible to use somehow the ajaxSubmitButton  with $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', .... ?

Comment: Can you take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409485/cactiveform-and-ajaxsubmitbutton-not-working ?